# How can i fix error when installing apk in droid device

Tags: java, android

I am android developer.
I developed simple android app using eclips tools .
The Android sdk that i used is Android 2.2

And i want test it my android device .
I already tested in ZTE and S3 gallaxy.
But when i test my app in droid Motorola , the error occur.
When i installing apk file .
There is error printed "encountered a problem in processing the package".
Would you explain that reason. Plz.

Motorola android os version is 2.2.3 
And my app is simple game . 
In the game i used cocos2d  library, libgdx.so.
Please help me.
Thanks .
han21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try uninstalling it from the device using the app manager in settings on the device or through adb using adb uninstall  this should fix your problem. Otherwise check that the device fits the specifications of the Android manifest.